# SQL Join using floating Where Date

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I have a 2 tables, one with activity generated information, the other with new contract information. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is see if within 30 days after the activity date, a new contract was generated. So for example:

[image: Activties]

[image: Contracts]

The first table is the activities table, the 2nd the contract table. As you'll see for example, account ABC123 does have a new contract within 30 days of the activity date - CT-7135. However, CT-7695, although it exists in the table and is associated with account ABC123, would not satisfaction the "New Contract" requirement b/c it started outside of the 30 window since the activity date.

Account GJ1234 however would be a "no" b/c there is no contract in the table that is within 30 days of the activity date. Likewise CGE435 (because of CT-4389) and GHE568 (because of contracts CT-4389, CT-8080 AND / OR CT-6690 ---- BUT NOT because of CT-6829) both qualify.

I guess my issue is trying to do this dynamic join off of activity date b/c it's different for each line items.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Distinct AccountId
From Accounts a
Where Exists
    (Select * From contracts
     Where AccountId = a.AccountId
       And ContractDate >= a.ActivityDate
       And DateDiff(day, a.ActivityDate, ContractDate) <= 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will find all the accounts that have had a new contract within 30 days of the activity:

```
SELECT * FROM activities AS A WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(AccountID) from contracts WHERE ContractStartDate >= A.ActivityDate AND ContractStartDate <= DATE_ADD(A.ActivityDate, INTERVAL DAY 30))
```